# How to merge conflicts in Visual Studio 2012 using Visual Studio Tools for Git

Tags: git, merge, visual-studio-2012

I have VS2012 with Update 2 installed. I've installed Visual Studio Tools for Git. Now I want o fetch changes from the remote repository, but they are in conflict with my local changes? How can I perform merge and/or edit conflicts?

Many thanks!

Comment: assuming the VS tools for GIT are well integrated, you should find the conflicts in View -> Other Windows -> Pending Changes, and select the "conflicts" button on the left side of the window. from there you should be able to automerge, merge in MS merge tool, Keep target, or Take Source.

Comment: @Frank, I've tried your solution but Im only getting this error: "Team Foundation Server is not the current Source Control plug-in. Change Plug-in"

Comment: sounds like they are not integrating the tools very well then. you will have to seek documentation from the publisher of the plugin. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to

> Tools > Options > Source Control

Change the plug-in to "Microsoft Git Provider", and then hit Ok. The solution window should now show you options to enter your default Git Settings.

NB - As per this Visual Studio [post](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c), Visual Studio 2013 includes Git tools by default, so this will not be needed.